# PubSub to Cloud Storage using DataFlow is slow

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I am using a slightly adjusted version of the following [example](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/samples/pubsub-to-gcs) snippet to write PubSub messages to GCS:

```py
class WriteToGCS(beam.DoFn):
    def __init__(self, output_path, prefix):
        self.output_path = output_path
        self.prefix = prefix

    def process(self, key_value, window=beam.DoFn.WindowParam):
        """Write messages in a batch to Google Cloud Storage."""

        start_date = window.start.to_utc_datetime().date().isoformat()
        start = window.start.to_utc_datetime().isoformat()
        end = window.end.to_utc_datetime().isoformat()
        shard_id, batch = key_value

        filename = f'{self.output_path}/{start_date}/{start}-{end}/{self.prefix}-{start}-{end}-{shard_id:03d}'

        with beam.io.gcsio.GcsIO().open(filename=filename, mode="w") as f:
            for message_body in batch:
                f.write(f"{message_body},".encode("utf-8"))
```

However, its terribly slow. [This is how it looks like in the graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5f0dl.png). Is there a way to speed up this step? The subscription gets 500 elements per second, so 3-10 elements per seconds is not keeping up.

The pipeline looks like this:

```py
class JsonWriter(beam.PTransform):
    def __init__(self, window_size, path, prefix, num_shards=20):
        self.window_size = int(window_size)
        self.path = path
        self.prefix = prefix
        self.num_shards = num_shards

    def expand(self, pcoll):
        return (
            pcoll
            | "Group into fixed windows" >> beam.WindowInto(window.FixedWindows(self.window_size, 0))
            | "Decode windowed elements" >> beam.ParDo(Decode())
            | "Group into batches" >> beam.BatchElements()
            | "Add key" >> beam.WithKeys(lambda _: random.randint(0, int(self.num_shards) - 1))
            | "Write to GCS" >> beam.ParDo(WriteToGCS(self.path, self.prefix))
        )
```

Comment: You can check this article [https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/request-rate#naming-convention] , modifying the file name pattern might help you to increase writing through-put

Comment: @Sach I tried that, but that does not seem to be the problem. I think the simultaneous writes to one of the sharded files is slowing down the process. Due to the randomness of keys, batches can have the same key and thus are written to the same file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this with these steps:

```py
            | "Add Path" >> beam.ParDo(AddFilename(self.path, self.prefix, self.num_shards))
            | "Group Paths" >> beam.GroupByKey()
            | "Join and encode" >> beam.ParDo(ToOneString())
            | "Write to GCS" >> beam.ParDo(WriteToGCS())
```

First I add the paths per element, then I group by path (to prevent simultaneous writes to the same file/shard). Then I concatenate (new line delimited) the JSON strings per group (path) and then write the whole string to the file. This reduces the calls to GCS tremendously, since I dont write every element one by one to a file, but instead join them first and then write once. Hope it helps someone.